# How can I include third column in a SELECT with MIN

Tags: sql, syntax, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

In this query, I also want to SELECT a third column, `wp_postmeta.post_id`, in the same query.  I can't figure out how to do this without appending it via a JOIN which involves subquerying.  Isn't there a simpler easier way, without the use of subqueries?  (Willing to concede on subqueries if the solution is efficient and not too resource-intensive.)

MariaDB 10.1

> ```
> create table wp_posts (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_title varchar(30),
>   post_type varchar(30)
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table wp_postmeta (
>   ID integer primary key auto_increment,
>   post_id integer,
>   meta_key varchar(30) not null default '_regular_price',
>   meta_value integer not null
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_posts (post_title, post_type) values
> ('Apple Pie','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Shepards Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Jam Pie','Product'),
> ('Plate','Not a Product'),
> ('Bucket','Not a Product'),
> ('Chequebook','Not a Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('French Toast','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product'),
> ('Banana','Product');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_value) values
> (1,10),
> (2,5),
> (3,9),
> (4,8),
> (5,11),
> (6,12),
> (7,10),
> (8,6),
> (9,1),
> (10,1),
> (11,7),
> (12,2),
> (13,2);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value) FROM wp_postmeta JOIN wp_posts
> ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
> WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
> GROUP BY wp_posts.post_title
> ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title
> ```
>
> ```
> post_title   | MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)
> :----------- | --------------------------:
> Apple Pie    |                          10
> Banana       |                           2
> French Toast |                           1
> Jam Pie      |                           8
> Shepards Pie |                           9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e870c88fc58fa9228f7d1ff996a14f8b)*

Edit: I wasn't clear and explicit enough in my original question - I want to collapse the duplicate `post_titles` and use the `wp_postmeta.post_id` corresponding to the `MIN(pm.meta_value)`

Comment: Since your version does not have CTEs, follow the [groupwise-maximum] tag for solution(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, your question can be solved using *window functions* :

```
SELECT x.post_title, x.id
FROM (
    SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wp_posts.post_title ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value) rn
    FROM wp_postmeta 
    INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id 
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'Product' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price'
) x WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

**[See this DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=55bebd99d7dcaed6e4115e880f707dcb)**

Window functions are the way to go for such use cases (if I understood it right). They usually beat Other solutions in terms of efficiency and readability.

---

If your RDBMS does not support window functions, one solution is to use a correlated subquery with a NOT EXISTS condition that ensures that there is no record with a smaller meta value for the given post title.

```
SELECT p.post_title, MIN(m.id)
FROM 
    wp_postmeta m
    INNER JOIN wp_posts p 
        ON  p.id = m.post_id
        AND p.post_type = 'Product' 
WHERE 
    m.meta_key = '_regular_price'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 
            wp_postmeta m1
            INNER JOIN wp_posts p1
                ON  p1.id = m1.post_id
                AND p1.post_type = 'Product'
        WHERE 
            m1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
            AND p1.post_title = p.post_title
            AND m1.meta_value < m.meta_value
     )
 GROUP BY p.post_title
```

**[DB Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f364b7b812aa5e091e624097878a7bc9)**

NB : I did a little cleaning in your SQL (added table alias and moved some condition to then ON clause of the relevant join).

Comment: Can you make this work for MariaDB 10.1?  Actually this was my original solution, however window functions support is patchy

Comment: @ptrcao Isn't that involving a subquery like you didn't want?

Comment: @Matthias  Good point.  If I had a choice, I'd rather not use a subquery because it complicates the code too much and I've found multiple subquery embedding to really slow down operations for some reason.  However, if that's the best you can do I'll take it.  However, window functions aren't supported on MariaDB 10.1 so this still isn't a viable solution unless I upgrade, which can introduce other complications elsewhere.

Comment: @ptrcao : I updated my answer with a solution without windowing,

Comment: @GMB  Your solution produces `post_title` duplicates?

Comment: @ptrcao : I added DISTINCT to the second query, would you please let me know if it works as expected now ?

Comment: @ptrcao : ok I see, that's because there are rows with even `meta_value`... I switched to `GROUP BY` and tested, it seems to work (see the fiddle).

Comment: Is it possible to get a single table with `post_title`, `min(pm.meta_value)` and `ID`corresponding to the `min(pm.meta_value)`?

Comment: @ptrcao : what do you call *a single table* ? It looks to me that this query is producing the results that you expect, without using window functions or CTE, hence it should properly answer your question...

Comment: When I ran this on production server, I got error: `mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections`.  Can you suggest anything helpful here?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just include it in the `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.id, MIN(pm.meta_value)
FROM wp_postmeta pm JOIN
     wp_posts p
     ON pm.post_id = p.id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'Product' AND pm.meta_key = '_regular_price' 
GROUP BY p.post_title, p.id
ORDER BY p.post_title;
```

The `post_id` is the same as `p.id`, so you might as well use that.

EDIT:

If the titles can be repeated, then simply use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.id, pm.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta pm JOIN
     wp_posts p
     ON pm.post_id = p.id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'Product' AND
      pm.meta_key = '_regular_price' AND
      pm.meta_value = (SELECT MIN(pm2.meta_value)
                       FROM wp_postmeta pm2 JOIN
                            wp_posts p2
                            ON pm2.post_id = p2.id 
                       WHERE p2.post_title = p.post_title
                      )
ORDER BY p.post_title;
```

Comment: I tried, but I wanted to collapse the duplicate `post_titles` and use the `p.id` corresponding to the `MIN(pm.meta_value)`

Answer (score 1):

You can tray with CTE:

```
WITH T1
AS ( SELECT   post_title, MIN(id) AS ID
     FROM     wp_posts
     GROUP BY post_title )
SELECT   T1.ID, wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)
FROM     wp_postmeta
         JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
         JOIN T1 ON T1.post_title = wp_posts.post_title
WHERE    wp_posts.post_type = 'Product'
         AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price'
GROUP BY T1.ID,  wp_posts.post_title
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title;
```

EDIT:

Your table wp_posts should look like this

```
Id, post_title, post_type
1, 'Apple Pie','Product'
2, 'French Toast','Product'
3, 'Shepards Pie','Product'
4, 'Jam Pie','Product'
5, 'Plate','Not a Product'
6, 'Bucket','Not a Product'
7, 'Chequebook','Not a Product'
8, 'Banana','Product'
```

and than you have in wp_postmeta table data like this

```
post_id, meta_value
1,  10
2,  5
3,  9
4,  8
4,  11
5,  12 
6,  10
7,  6
2,  1
2,  1
8,  7
8,  2
8,  2
```

and query look like this

```
SELECT   wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_posts.post_title, MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)
FROM     wp_postmeta
         JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
WHERE    wp_posts.post_type = 'Product'
         AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'REG PRICE'
GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id,  wp_posts.post_title
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title;
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain the original correspondence between `wp_postmeta.meta_value` and `ID`.  It's not that I want the minimum ID in each group; I want the ID for the row that corresponds to the `MIN(wp_postmeta.meta_value)` in the original table rows

Comment: You have a duplicate ID for product Banana and Freanch Toast with same MIN meta_value. If you do not use MIN function in T1 you will get duplicate post_title.

Comment: Good point.  However, is there another aggregate function that can be used which instead of using the group's min ID value, will retrieve the ID of the row from which MIN meta_value is derived?  (I want to maintain the relationship between ID and meta_value).  Thank you

Comment: You should prevent duplicate rows in your table wp_posts. Create one table with list all your product and non product. That table should have a two columns ID and Name. ID from new table will be use in tabel wp_postmeta in column Post_Id.

Comment: If you have time, please show me what you mean.  However, I worry that creating copies of tables in a very large database could be resource-intensive?