# PHPMyAdmin Database connection errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, runtime-error, mariadb

I ran query to this effect:

```
SELECT x.minid FROM (SELECT p.post_title, MIN(p.ID) as minid, m.meta_value
FROM 
    wp_postmeta m
    INNER JOIN wp_posts p 
        ON  p.id = m.post_id
        AND p.post_type = 'Product' 
WHERE 
    m.meta_key = '_regular_price'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM 
            wp_postmeta m1
            INNER JOIN wp_posts p1
                ON  p1.id = m1.post_id
                AND p1.post_type = 'Product'
        WHERE 
            m1.meta_key = '_regular_price'
            AND p1.post_title = p.post_title
            AND m1.meta_value < m.meta_value
```

And after a long time running the query, it finally threw up this error:

```
Error
SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit


SELECT `CHARACTER_SET_NAME` AS `Charset`, `DESCRIPTION` AS `Description` FROM `information_schema`.`CHARACTER_SETS`
Open new phpMyAdmin window
 mysqli_connect(): (08004/1040): Too many connections
 mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'ptrcao'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
 mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'ptrcao'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Notice in ./libraries/classes/Config.php#855
 Undefined index: collation_connection

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Config.php#968: PhpMyAdmin\Config->_setConnectionCollation()
./libraries/common.inc.php#453: PhpMyAdmin\Config->loadUserPreferences()
./index.php#26: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
Notice in ./libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php#1501
 Undefined index: charset_connection

Backtrace

./libraries/classes/Config.php#857: PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->setCollation(string 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
./libraries/classes/Config.php#968: PhpMyAdmin\Config->_setConnectionCollation()
./libraries/common.inc.php#453: PhpMyAdmin\Config->loadUserPreferences()
./index.php#26: require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)
 Failed to set configured collation connection!
Notice in ./index.php#264
 Undefined variable: collation_connection

Backtrace
```

[Previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54585491/phpmyadmin-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query), I was having problems with the queries maxing out my memory resources.  I then added on 16G of swap memory as a stopgap measure.  It seemed to staved off the `#2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query` error encountered previously, but instead after a long time running, the query produced all the above errors.  Please advise.

/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main interface for database interactions
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin-DBI
 */
namespace PhpMyAdmin;

use PhpMyAdmin\Core;
use PhpMyAdmin\Database\DatabaseList;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiExtension;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiDummy;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysql;
use PhpMyAdmin\Dbi\DbiMysqli;
use PhpMyAdmin\Di\Container;
use PhpMyAdmin\Error;
use PhpMyAdmin\Index;
use PhpMyAdmin\LanguageManager;
use PhpMyAdmin\Relation;
use PhpMyAdmin\SystemDatabase;
use PhpMyAdmin\Table;
use PhpMyAdmin\Types;
"DatabaseInterface.php" 3060L, 104788C
```

/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/libraries/classes/Config.php:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Configuration handling.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */
namespace PhpMyAdmin;

use DirectoryIterator;
use PhpMyAdmin\Core;
use PhpMyAdmin\Error;
use PhpMyAdmin\LanguageManager;
use PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager;
use PhpMyAdmin\Url;
use PhpMyAdmin\UserPreferences;
use PhpMyAdmin\Util;
use PhpMyAdmin\Utils\HttpRequest;

/**
 * Indication for error handler (see end of this file).
 */
$GLOBALS['pma_config_loading'] = false;

/**
 * Configuration class
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */
class Config
{
    /**
     * @var string  default config source
     */
    var $default_source = './libraries/config.default.php';

    /**
     * @var array   default configuration settings
     */
    var $default = array();

    /**
     * @var array   configuration settings, without user preferences applied
     */
    var $base_settings = array();

    /**
     * @var array   configuration settings
     */
    var $settings = array();

    /**
     * @var string  config source
     */
    var $source = '';

    /**
     * @var int     source modification time
     */
    var $source_mtime = 0;
    var $default_source_mtime = 0;
"Config.php" 1800L, 57604C
```

/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php:

```
<?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * Main loader script
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */
use PhpMyAdmin\Charsets;
use PhpMyAdmin\Config;
use PhpMyAdmin\Core;
use PhpMyAdmin\Display\GitRevision;
use PhpMyAdmin\LanguageManager;
use PhpMyAdmin\Message;
use PhpMyAdmin\RecentFavoriteTable;
use PhpMyAdmin\Relation;
use PhpMyAdmin\Response;
use PhpMyAdmin\Sanitize;
use PhpMyAdmin\Server\Select;
use PhpMyAdmin\ThemeManager;
use PhpMyAdmin\Url;
use PhpMyAdmin\Util;

/**
 * Gets some core libraries and displays a top message if required
 */
require_once 'libraries/common.inc.php';

/**
 * pass variables to child pages
 */
$drops = array(
    'lang',
    'server',
    'collation_connection',
    'db',
    'table'
);
foreach ($drops as $each_drop) {
    if (array_key_exists($each_drop, $_GET)) {
        unset($_GET[$each_drop]);
    }
}
unset($drops, $each_drop);

/*
 * Black list of all scripts to which front-end must submit data.
 * Such scripts must not be loaded on home page.
 *
 */
$target_blacklist = array (
    'import.php', 'export.php'
);

// If we have a valid target, let's load that script instead
if (! empty($_REQUEST['target'])
    && is_string($_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! preg_match('/^index/', $_REQUEST['target'])
    && ! in_array($_REQUEST['target'], $target_blacklist)
    && Core::checkPageValidity($_REQUEST['target'], [], true)
) {
    include $_REQUEST['target'];
"index.php" 680L, 19899C
```

Comment: Can you show the file(s) where it says the error is? I.e. `Config.php`, `DatabaseInterface.php` and `index.php`? One error indicates that you might be trying to establish multiple connections. You should just establish one connection. One is a classic access denied error, so it could be that your database config php file is not using the correct settings. etc. etc.

Comment: Where are these files located?  I'm not sure about the relative positioning of those file paths...

Comment: The error is telling you exactly where the file is located @ptrcao :) The Config.php file is located in the folder called libraries, which then again have a subfolder called classes. That is where you will find the file Config.php.  Same goes for DatabaseInterface.php, and index.php should be in the root directory.

Comment: Forgive me, but where is the libraries folder?  Which folder does it sit in?  I'm not a database administrator, I'm unfamiliar...  The dot slash `./` I assume refers to the current directory, but I'm not sure what the presumed current directory is.

Comment: try and do a file search if you are unable to locate the directories manually.

Comment: `SELECT p.post_title, MIN(p.ID) as minid` is not meaningful -- It will give you the min `ID`, but a random `title`.  Perhaps you need "groupwise-maximum"?

Comment: @Martin See original post - hopefully I have copied the contents of the correct files...  What do you make of it?

Comment: @RickJames  Thanks for pointing that out!  The query you see derives from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563951/9095603).  I'm still new to SQL, so I'll need to ponder a bit to fully appreciate what you mean.  Or if you have the time and patience, you could elaborate in terms that a newbie can understand...

Comment: The error seems to go deeper as those files yet again include the use of other files. Try and see if you can find the file that sets up the database connection and settings for it. Judging by your query, you're using wordpress. There should be an easily accessible file called config.php, possibly in your root directory iirc. Haven't used WordPress in a while.

Comment: @Martin Do you mean [wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php)?  I can't post that can I, as it contains sensitive security details?

Comment: Yes, but look at the connection and make sure that everything is as you expect it to be @ptrcao

Comment: Unfortunately, I wouldn't know what to look for...

Comment: @ptrcao - re: not meaningful -- search this forum and the online docs for `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: @RickJames You mean the error that comes up?  `[42000][1055] Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'blog.c.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`  Isn't this constraint already enforced by modern versions of SQL/MariaDB?

Comment: @ptrcao - Yes, but only in the newer versions.  Currently, _most_ of the Questions on this forum involve _older_ versions.  Since the OP failed to mention the version, I took the leap to assume it was 'old'.

Comment: @ptrcao - The 5.7.5 Changelog (in 2014) gives a clue of why it was not the default long ago:  'only_full_group_by is defaulted and the "functional dependence" checking is implemented'